# pass variables and instances in side wordpress widget class to new custom function

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make a custom ajax function in side wordpress widget class but I couldn't pass the instances and some variables in side a widget method to my new custom ajax method...

```
   class Emailer_Widget extends WP_Widget
      {

        public function __construct()
      {
      $options = array(
      'description' => __('Emailer Widget','onepage'),
      'classname'   => 'emailer-widget',
      );
      parent::__construct(
      'op_emailer_widget', //Base ID
     __('OP Emailer Widget','onopage'), //Name
      $options
  );
    $this->adder();
   }
   public function adder() {
    add_action('wp_ajax_mailerformValidation', array($this,       'emailer_form_sender')); // Call when user logged in
           add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mailerformValidation', array($this,   'emailer_form_sender')); // Call when user in not logged in
       add_filter( 'some_event_action',array($this, 'emailer_form_sender') );
        }
     public function widget($args, $instance) {
    //some form here
     }
   public function form($instance) {
      $title                 = apply_filters('widget_title',  empty($instance['title']) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
      $message               = ! empty( $instance['message'] ) ? $instance['message'] : '';
      $to_email              = ! empty( $instance['to_email'] ) ? $instance['to_email'] : '';
      $subject               = ! empty( $instance['subject'] ) ? $instance['subject'] : '';
?>
<!-- Widget Title -->
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'onepage' ); ?></label>
  <input id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
</p>

<!-- Text -->
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'message' )); ?>"><?php _e( 'Input Text:', 'onepage' ) ?></label>
  <textarea id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'message' )); ?>"  name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'message' )); ?>" style="min-height: 150px;"><?php echo esc_attr( $message ); ?></textarea>
</p>

<!-- email subject -->
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'subject' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Email Subject:', 'onepage' ); ?></label>
  <input id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'subject' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'subject' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $subject ); ?>" />
</p>

<!-- email destination -->
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'to_email' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Email Destination:', 'onepage' ); ?></label>
  <input id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'to_email' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'to_email' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $to_email ); ?>" />
</p>



    }
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance ){
   }
    public function emailer_form_validation() {
     // I wanna pass the instance values to here and the form values to     here 
     }
```

The only problem is emailer_form_validation() method can't access instances and variables from other method...

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the class by reference:

```
public function adder() {
    add_action('wp_ajax_mailerformValidation', array(&$this,       'emailer_form_sender')); // Call when user logged in
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mailerformValidation', array(&$this,   'emailer_form_sender')); // Call when user in not logged in
    add_filter( 'some_event_action',array(&$this, 'emailer_form_sender') );
}
```

So instead of `$this` it's `&$this` [more info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Also keep in mind to pass variables you need to assign them to the class. So if you want to access the `$options` from the constructor. You should also set them to the class, so at the top of the form

```
public function form( $instance ) {
    $title    = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
    $message  = ! empty( $instance['message'] ) ? $instance['message'] : '';
    $to_email = ! empty( $instance['to_email'] ) ? $instance['to_email'] : '';
    $subject  = ! empty( $instance['subject'] ) ? $instance['subject'] : '';

    $this->title = $title;     
    $this->message = $message;   
    $this->to_email = $to_email;  
    $this->subject = $subject;

    // the rest of the form
}
```

Now you can access the variables in `emailer_form_validation()` method using `$this->message`.
To see all variables set in a class just `var_dump($this)` and check the output.

Comment: thank you for answering, I have tried your way but still can't share the instances to my new mothed ….my new mothed can't access instances values from form mothed...any other solution?

Comment: It's called a method, not mothed

Comment: In your code I don't see the body of the `form()` method. So I don't know what's going on there. Do you assign variables to the class using `$this->varName`?

Comment: I have edited my code, go check it again... please try to help me... and mothed was just a typo...

Comment: I wanna use the variables inside of `form()` like `$message` as an example in side of `emailer_form_validation()` method...

Comment: @shadi see my edit. Pretty much the same answer, but with an example specific for you.

Comment: sorry but it didn't work... I don't no why... this is going to drive me crazy. and when I use `var_dump($this)` inside `emailer_form_validation()` I can't see the variables from `form()`method..

Comment: Ahh of course, that is because the mehtod `form()` has not run (yet), so it didn't set the variables. So it would be better to declare these variables in the `__constructor()` method.

Comment: How exactly? example?

Comment: Looking again closely what you are trying to achieve, it's not gonna work. Because you can have multiple instances of this 1 widget class with multiple `$message` values. And the ajax call can't know which instance you are looking at. You will need a different approach. I'm not sure what.